# Proxy Access to my Squid Proxy

Tags: proxy, squid, http-proxy

I have a squid proxy cluster to let my users surf in the internet and on intranet ressources.

Now there is a special user, that wants to configure another squid in the net of the users.
So this proxy wants to access the internet over a proxy-proxy configuration.

It doesnt work at the moment.

So here is the question: Whats the configuration line for my squid.conf to allow an IP to use my squid as an upstream proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have two proxies:

```
 ________       _________       _________       __________
| client | --> | proxy B | --> | proxy A | --> { internet }
|________|     |_________|     |_________|     {__________}
              port           port
              8000           8080
```

Your configuration for proxy A already works so we'll ignore that for now. The difference is that *proxy B* must be configured to send all requests to a proxy, not the internet. So how do to this in Squid for proxy B's configuration?

Investigate the [cache_peer](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer/) configuration directive.

Something like (for proxy B):

```
http_port 8000
cache_peer proxy_A parent 8080 0 no-query
```

Comment: So there is no difference for proxy A whether to handle an user or a proxy?

Comment: No. You don't need to alter proxy A.

Answer (score 1):

On one proxy (the client side), you need to define the `cache_peer`.

On the other proxy (the server side), you need to define the appropriate `acl` line to allow the proxy IP to use this proxy.